# Tabbed UI with TabHost. Tabs icons dont show

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I just done this walkthrough and everything is fine, but I have no icons on tabs. [Walkthrough](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/tab_layout/Walkthrough_Creating_a_tabbed_ui/) I have phone with android 4.4. It is possible that android 4.4 dont alllow TabHost anymore?

Some code.

Main cs file

```cs
namespace com.xamarin.example.tabhostwalkthrough
{
    using System;

    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Widget;

    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher")]
    public class TabHostWalkthrough : TabActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            CreateTab(typeof(WhatsOnActivity), "whats_on", "What's On", Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_whats_on);
            CreateTab(typeof(SpeakersActivity), "speakers", "Speakers", Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_speakers);
            CreateTab(typeof(SessionsActivity), "sessions", "Sessions", Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_sessions);
            CreateTab(typeof(MyScheduleActivity), "my_schedule", "My Schedule", Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_my_schedule);
        }
        private void CreateTab(Type activityType, string tag, string label, int drawableId)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, activityType);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            var spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec(tag);
            var drawableIcon = Resources.GetDrawable(drawableId);
            spec.SetIndicator(label, drawableIcon);
            spec.SetContent(intent);

            TabHost.AddTab(spec);
        }
    }
}
```

Tab xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_my_schedule_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_my_schedule_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

.axml file to main cs file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Ok I find a solution. i just added a theme in manifest file like this and problem solved
<application android:label="App"   
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">

Comment: But when I add Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar, icons dont show :/ Theme.Light looks awful :(